# In Word 2007, how to find&replace using wildcards for find without replacing the substring defined by the wildcards?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office-2007, find-and-replace, wildcards

I have a document where there are many instances of two pieces of information on a single line, like

```
 assigned to John Doe, estimate 2 days
```

and I want them to appear on two different lines, like

```
assigned to: John Doe
estimate: 2 days
```

but when I tried using wildcards, I didn't go far. My best guess was: find `assigned to*, estimate*\p`replace with `assigned to:*\p estimate:*\p`
and of course, this did not produce the desired result, but

```
assigned to:*
estimate:*
```

How do I specify a wildcard in Find and direct Replace to keep the same content which was found with the wildcard, but changing the content around it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to use [Regexp](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/support/add-power-to-word-searches-with-regular-expressions-HA001087305.aspx?redir=0).

Search expression:

```
assigned to (<*>) (<*>)
```

Replace expression:

```
assigned to: \1 \2 ^p
```

So that takes care of splitting the name. For the estimates:

Search expression

```
, estimate (<*>) (<*>)
```

Replace expression

```
estimate: \1 \2
```

---

Test case:

[image]

Search for `assigned to (<*>) (<*>)` and replace with `assigned to: \1 \2 ^p`

[image]

[image]

Search for `, estimate (<*>) (<*>)` and replace with `estimate: \1 \2`

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

you can use 2 find and replaces which worked for me, one that was 
Find Assigned to 
and replace Assigned To:

the second 
find , estimate
and replace ^13estimate:

^13 will add a CRLF

Comment: The idea occured to me, but I still want to find out if there is a way to do it using the wildcards, because 1. Next time I could have a harder problem to solve where there is no easy two-step-solution and 2. It is improbable, but possible, that `assigned to` or `, estimate` appears somewhere else in the document, while the combination of both is more likely to be unique

Comment: I got it all to work in one for you with the following FIND assigned to, (<*>) (<*>), estimate (<*>) (<*>) AND REPLACE Assigned to: \1 \2 ^13Estimate: \3 \4 --make sure you are using wildcards